# How come correctness proofs aren't tautological?

Tags: logic, correctness-proof

Consider the following function on binary trees, which is supposed to tell whether a given `int` is a member of a binary tree `t`:

```
type tree = Leaf | Node of int * tree * tree;;

let rec tmember (t:tree) (x:int) : bool =
  match t with
      Leaf -> false
    | Node (j,left,right) -> j = x || tmember left x || tmember right x
;;
```

If one wants to prove that this function is correct, one would need to *define* first what tree membership actually means, but then I can find no formal way of doing this except for saying that `x` is a member of `t` if and only if it is either equal to the root of `t`, or it is a member of the left or right subtree of `t`. This is essentially saying that `x` is a member of `t` if and only if  `tmember t x` outputs `true`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Some things have to be taken primitively before properties can be proven, such as `tmember`. However, you can still prove things about it that you would expect of a membership relation, such as empty trees have no elements and if you insert an element into a tree then `tmember` gives true.

Comment: This seems to demonstrate the elegance of the functional paradigm: correctness is often “self evident” from the code. Consider the procedural paradigm, where you might want to prove tmember is true if and only if  x was added ad some point in the past but not yet removed.

Comment: @MusaAl-hassy do you mean that the membership relation cannot be stated in more general terms, and therefore one should define it as being the output of the `tmember` function?

Comment: Yes, using it as a starting point you can then define subset and equality relationships. Then check the expected properties, such as 'casting' $x \in X \subseteq Y \to x \in Y$; if the usual elementary properties cannot be proven, then you know something's wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Membership is much more general than this recursive definition you give. At a higher level you could define membership as follows:

> A *tree* can be defined as a collection of nodes, $V$, and edges $E$ where those edges and nodes satisfy particular [constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)).
>
> We say a value $x$ is a *member of the tree* if and only if there is a node $v$ in $V$ such that the value of $v$ is equivalent to $x$.

You then *prove* (probably with induction since it's recursive) that your function is equivalent to this definition. That is to say, your function returns true on value $x$ if and only if there is a node $v$ in $V$ such that the value of $v$ is equivalent to $x$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are suggesting that the specification be written in terms of these graph theoretic notions. But what if one were to use only set theoretic notions, as described [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=WnkZSSc4IkoC&pg=PA620) ? I think in that case the specification would correspond roughly to what I wrote in my question.

Comment: It seems you've deferred one notion of membership for another, then @Nicolas will have to prove *that* definition is correct ;-)

Comment: @Musa you don't have to prove definitions are correct, that's why it's a definition. You prove that the function returns true if and only if the definition is satisfied. I guess you could choose whichever definition you want, but set membership is much more general than the definition provided in the question.

Comment: Whatever the case, pick a definition and prove that your function returns true iff that is satisfied. Whether or not the definition is what you want is another question.

Comment: @Nicolas if you stick with your original definition of tree membership then the proof just becomes easier. You prove it for the base case (empty tree), then prove inductively that it holds for a tree of size $n$.

Comment: @ryan, you're not wrong, but there's subtelty I suppose, idk. E.g., the identity function is *specfified* by $Id\ x = x$, but the *implementation* `Id(x){ sleep-for(100s); return x;}` *appears* correct, but it could also be wrong. Idk, I had a direction when I started typing but have lost it; regardless, I agree with your words.